# How to test platform event trigger enqueuing async jobs?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, platform-event

How can I test that a trigger listener on my platform event object enqueued an async Apex job? My use case for enqueuing an async job is that the job needs to make a callout to an external service. The callout is [not possible within the trigger listener](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176570&type=1) itself.

Below is a simplified concept of what I'm trying to do. There [doesn't seem to be a way to test that the job was enqueued or executed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191456/queueable-apex-not-working-in-platform-event-trigger/209053#209053) at the current time, due to what may be a limitation in `Test.stopTest()`.

```
trigger AsyncHelloEventTrigger on AsyncHelloEvent__e (after insert) {
    System.enqueueJob(new HelloJob(Trigger.new));
}
```

I thought about wrapping the call to `System.enqueueJob` in a service, but my next question would be, "How can I stub the service?"

```
trigger AsyncHelloEventTrigger on AsyncHelloEvent__e (after insert) {
    ApexJobService.getInstance().enqueueJob(new HelloJob(Trigger.new));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a pattern like the below for simple mocking:

```
public virtual with sharing class MyService
{
    static MyService instance = new MyService();
    @TestVisible static void setMock(MyService mock) { instance = mock; }

    public static Id enqueueJob(List<MyObject__e> records)
    {
        return instance.doEnqueueJob(records);
    }

    protected virtual Id doEnqueueJob(List<MyObject__e> records)
    {
        return system.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(records));
    }
}
```

Then in your test you can mock it out quite easily. You don't really need to test what the service does so much as that it gets called.

```
class MockService extends MyService
{
    Integer calls = 0;
    protected override Id doEnqueueJob(List<MyObject__e> records)
    {
        calls++;
        return null;
    }
}
@IsTest static void testEnqueueJob()
{
    // set up data
    MyService mock = new MockService();

    Test.startTest();
        MyService.setMock(mock);
        // publish events
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, mock.calls, 'The service should be called');
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, that your solution doesn't even require the [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm)! Thanks Adrian!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up an answer to the linked question that might be helpful - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/297694/54914

Comment: Very interesting! I'd never seen the [Test.getEventBus().deliver()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_test_deliver.htm) method before.